# The minimal time interval of TumblingProcessingTimeWindow

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

When I set `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows.of(Time.milliseconds(100)))`, The windows can be generated correctly. I print the windowStartTime and windowEndTime here:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2znxt.png)

But if I change the interval to `Time.milliseconds(50)`, the interval between windows is not exectly 50ms.By this I mean windows are not consecutive. The result shows below:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVoqD.png)

I want to know whether there is a minimal time interval of `TumblingProcessingTimeWindows` we can set in flink, eg. 100ms. What if I want to generate a shorter one, can I achieve this by rewriting a `WindowAssigner` function? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If the throughput isn't sufficient to fill the network buffers sooner, then you'll want to set the network buffer timeout to something smaller than the default (which is 100 ms), e.g.,

```java
env.setBufferTimeout(10L); // configure 10 ms buffer timeout
```

or you can set `execution.buffer-timeout.interval` in flink-conf.yaml, e.g.,

```yaml
execution.buffer-timeout.interval: 10
```

See the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/config/#execution-buffer-timeout-interval) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

There is no minimum window size (other than > 0). But no window will be created if no event is received with a timestamp for that window. So my guess is that with the shorter window, you occasionally get a 50ms period with no data for whatever key value you're using.